# Captcha broken after site move

Tags: php, captcha

Ive recently moved servers for my website. However the captcha function (which is pulled in from captcha.php isnt working. Ive checked permissions and it all seems fine, what else could be going wrong?
[The site](http://edexec.co.uk/subscribe/)

The Captcha form is towards the bottom. Ive a feeling its something simple Im missing!

Captcha.php:

```
<?php
//Start the session so we can store what the security code actually is
session_start();

//Send a generated image to the browser 
create_image(); 
exit(); 

function create_image() 
{ 

    // Set the content-type
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 30);

    // Create some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

    // The text to draw
    $text =  $_SESSION["captcha"];
    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'caviardreams.ttf';

    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

    // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
} 

?>
```

And here is the fix (Add $font = realpath($font);):

```
<?php
//Start the session so we can store what the security code actually is
session_start();

//Send a generated image to the browser 
create_image(); 
exit(); 

function create_image() 
{ 

    // Set the content-type
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 30);

    // Create some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

    // The text to draw
    $text =  $_SESSION["captcha"];
    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'caviardreams.ttf';
    $font = realpath($font);

    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

    // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
} 

?>
```

Comment: Does the new server have GD? I highly suggest implementing something like reCaptcha to make it easier on you, and your users (since it has built-in accessibility features).

Comment: Your [image generation script](http://www.edexec.co.uk/captcha.php) is producing what appears to be a valid PNG, so my money's on having the correct fonts on the server (I am presuming it uses wobbly text to implement the captcha test).

Comment: After having a look at the error log, it seems it is the font: [Tue May 08 18:24:28 2012] [error] [client 94.174.84.164] PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/edexec/captcha.php on line 33, referer: http://www.edexec.co.uk/subscribe/ However the font is there, with 644 permissions...

Comment: check /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/edexec/captcha.php on line 33 to see where should the font path be.

Comment: Hmm line 33 is where the text is created:

Comment: I worked it out... The new server has an updated version of PHP and GD... I needed to add this to the captcha.php:

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine it requires PHP to have [GD installed](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), but it's impossible to tell without knowing the errors your server is encountering when trying to render the captcha. Check your logs.